# Python client returns CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED on GRPC stub

Tags: python-3.x, macos, docker, grpc-python

I have this easy code to connect to download some data using `GRPC`

```
creds = grpc.ssl_channel_credentials()
channel = grpc.secure_channel(f'{HOST}:{PORT}', credentials=creds)
stub = liveops_pb2_grpc.LiveOpsStub(channel=channel)
request = project_pb2.ListProjectsRequest(organization=ORGANIZATION)
projects = stub.ListProjects(request=request)
print(projects)
```

This worked fine on wednesday. It runs in a docker container with `Python 3.8.10` and `protobuf==3.18.0`,`grpcio==1.40.0`, `grpcio-tools==1.40.0`.

Today I updated `MAC OS Big Sur to 11.6` and after finishing some extra features on the code I see that it returns:

```
E0930 21:12:04.108551900       1 ssl_transport_security.cc:1468] Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED.
E0930 21:12:04.194319000       1 ssl_transport_security.cc:1468] Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED.
E0930 21:12:04.286163700       1 ssl_transport_security.cc:1468] Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 302, in <module>
    projects = liveops_stub.ListProjects(request=request)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 946, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 849, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _InactiveRpcError(state)
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE
    details = "failed to connect to all addresses"
    debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1633036324.286560700","description":"Failed to pick subchannel","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.cc","file_line":3186,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1633036324.286548700","description":"failed to connect to all addresses","file":"src/core/lib/transport/error_utils.cc","file_line":146,"grpc_status":14}]}"
>
```

Seems to be something related to SSL Certificates.
If I check `/etc/ssl/certs` folder it is empty, so could be that SSL SO certificate has been erased?

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Let's Encrypt cross-signed DST Root CA X3 [expired](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/help-thread-for-dst-root-ca-x3-expiration-september-2021/149190/212) yesterday, it caused some SSL problems on some clients. I managed to fix it by manually changing the intermediate chain to use the new `Root X1` instead.
On the server, run:

```
sudo certbot certonly --nginx -d <ADDRESS> --preferred-chain "ISRG Root X1"
```

If you are not running nginx you might need to replace it with your server, and make sure to restart it.

Comment: Yes, i just fixed it. I will provide an answer too as I am not running nginx. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As Firas Al Mannaa said Let's Encrypt cross-signed DST Root CA X3 expired yesterday, it caused some SSL problems on some clients.

I added a new function to get a certificate from ca-bundle:

```
def get_ssl_certificate():
    request_response = req.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bagder/ca-bundle/master/ca-bundle.crt')
    certificate_content = request_response.text
    certificate_as_bytes = str.encode(certificate_content)

    return certificate_as_bytes
```

And then I used this certificate

```
creds = grpc.ssl_channel_credentials(root_certificates=certificate_as_bytes)
```